# Problems with deploying Next js to the cloud

Tags: node.js, cloud-hosting

I am using A2Hosting vendor to deploy my Next js app as a server. I have written all the scripts and tested on my local machine, but when I deploy it to the webserver and run
npm run build this is what happens:

```
throw errnoException(err, 'spawn'); ^
Error: spawn ENOMEM
at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:394:11)
at spawn (child_process.js:540:9)
at Object.fork (child_process.js:108:10)
at ChildProcessWorker.initialize (/home/briddgyc/nodevenv/Br-Front/12/lib/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/ChildProcessWorker.js:137:44)
at new ChildProcessWorker (/home/briddgyc/nodevenv/Br-Front/12/lib/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/ChildProcessWorker.js:127:10)
at WorkerPool.createWorker (/home/briddgyc/nodevenv/Br-Front/12/lib/node_modules/jest-worker/build/WorkerPool.js:44:12)
at new BaseWorkerPool (/home/briddgyc/nodevenv/Br-Front/12/lib/node_modules/jest-worker/build/base/BaseWorkerPool.js:82:27)
at new WorkerPool (/home/briddgyc/nodevenv/Br-Front/12/lib/node_modules/jest-worker/build/WorkerPool.js:30:1)
at new JestWorker (/home/briddgyc/nodevenv/Br-Front/12/lib/node_modules/jest-worker/build/index.js:131:26)
at TaskRunner.run (/home/briddgyc/nodevenv/Br-Front/12/lib/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/plugins/terser-webpack-plugin/src/TaskRunner.js:3:202)       {
errno: 'ENOMEM',
code: 'ENOMEM',
syscall: 'spawn'
}
```

I have checked that this is some kind of memory issue but 2 days and still cannot figure out anything.
I have still 40 Process and 700mb of RAM in my machine it should be sufficient I suppose.
Any recommendations ?

Comment: did you resolve the issue?

Comment: No, I deployed to Google App engine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have received a reply from support saying that the only way is to compile locally.

The process took more than 110% of CPU and reached 50/50 maxing the number of processes, and I'm still halfway through the project. Adding more commands that might even require more resources for compilation later on, I would rather stay safe and locally compile.